# How to recover faulty USB drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs

I was asked to help read a friend's USB disk, a WD My Passport 1TB.  The disk was used on Windows (unknown version), but I'm using a Mac.

When plugged in, the partition does not mount. In Disk Utility the device shows up but the single partition is greyed out.

With `diskutil list` I get:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS Monyjc                  1.0 TB     disk2s1
```

With `diskutil info` I get (omitting other drives):

```
diskutil info -all

    Device Identifier:        disk2
    Device Node:              /dev/disk2
    Whole:                    Yes
    Part of Whole:            disk2
    Device / Media Name:      My Passport 0830

    Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

    Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

    File System:              None

    Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
    OS Can Be Installed:      No
    Media Type:               Generic
    Protocol:                 USB
    SMART Status:             Not Supported
 
    Total Size:               1.0 TB (1000170586112 Bytes) (exactly 1953458176 512-Byte-Units)
    Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
    Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

    Read-Only Media:          No
    Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

    Device Location:          External
    Removable Media:          No
 
    Virtual:                  No
    OS 9 Drivers:             No
    Low Level Format:         Not supported
 
 **********
 
    Device Identifier:        disk2s1
    Device Node:              /dev/disk2s1
    Whole:                    No
    Part of Whole:            disk2
    Device / Media Name:      Untitled 1
 
    Volume Name:              Monyjc

    Mounted:                  No

    File System Personality:  NTFS
    Type (Bundle):            ntfs
    Name (User Visible):      Windows NT File System (NTFS)

    Partition Type:           Windows_NTFS
```

Trying to read the partition table tells me the resource is busy (after a while, sometimes a long while):

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=diskdata2 count=2 bs=512
Password:
dd: /dev/disk2: Resource busy
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 3.006429 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

And `fdisk` gives an empty table after a delay, perhaps because it also couldn't read the data (though there's no error reported):

```
$ sudo fdisk   /dev/disk2
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 121597/255/63 [1953458176 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Would I be right to assume that the partition table is not actually empty - because `diskutil` determined that it is an NTFS? Otherwise how does it know the partition type?

The delays that occur when doing various commands vary - at the moment, a second or so, but earlier they were tens of seconds. Does this imply that the disk is defective, quite apart from (perhaps) missing a partition table? Or just that the programs are scanning the disk (though `dd` surely can't be doing that).

Does anyone have suggestions for how to recover the disk and its data?

---

EDIT

This morning I put the drive in the freezer for half an hour and then tried it. It worked and over the course of the day I copied off the contents of the disk (only 20GB). The transfer was rather slow, but hopefully successful (I haven't verified that the files are intact - they're not mine and the names make them look private). The disk failed again just after the copy completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover hard disk data after deleting partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data-after-deleting-partitions)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I'm not sure a list of Windows software recommendations is quite what I'd call a duplicate.

Comment: if the device shows up the device mounts, when you mean is that the partition does not mount, correct? (I corrected your question, since there seems to be confusion about that, please check if I did it correctly).

Comment: @Albin - you can't 'mount' a device, only a volume/partition. William - 'greyed out' in itself just means it isn't currently mounted. Have you actually tried selecting that partition & hitting the 'Mount' button [I know you probably have, but just to be absolutely sure]. Does it spring any error when you do?

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok I'm a little confused about the terminology here (sorry if I have been "playing fast ans loose with it"). So the "volume" (regardless of it's actual data content) gets mounted but not the "partition"? I'll have to read up. What you be so kind an check if my change to the question was correct or should I have written `the volume does not mount`?

Comment: for NTFS, FAT or HFS, the terms 'volume' & 'partition' are pretty much interchangeable; you mount a partition as a volume, so people often use them to mean the same thing.. Only when you get to APFS does the difference become significant, & you then need a third term, 'container'.

Comment: This is from 2021?!  I thought the freezer trick was long since obsolete!  Maybe it was an overheating problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to look like a list pf product recommendations, I'm afraid…
…but Mac can't natively write to NTFS, so anything that could 'fix' the drive is going to need to first be addressed through an NTFS enabler. [This is technically possible for free using FUSE, but it is often flaky & I wouldn't trust it for any critical task.] [Paragon NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) is the one I use. Combined with [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) you *may* have a hope of actually fixing the structure.

Once you can better access the drive, then scavenger software such as [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com) might be handy, if the structure itself cannot be repaired..

If you're happy playing in Terminal, then `dd` is built-in & free. See http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302225659382 for some usage guidelines.

A common suggestion for data rescue is [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which frankly I've never been able to make head nor tail of. It just complains you must run it as root… not sure how you're going to do *that* on a mac.

All of these methods except the first - trying to fix the drive itself from Hard Disk Manager - will require you to have sufficient spare drive space to recover to. You want to avoid at all costs actually writing to the drive you're trying to recover.

Alternatively, test if the enclosure has failed - remove the drive & connect by an alternative method. This would be easier if you have a big ol' Mac Pro with lots of spare drive slots; otherwise you'll need a hardware dock of some sort.

You might consider a fourth option - a data recovery specialist.

..and then recommend to your friend they ought to consider backups to be an important part of running a computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This morning I put the drive in the freezer for half an hour and then tried it. It worked and over the course of the day I have copied off the contents of the disk (only 20GB). The disk failed again just after the copy completed.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: stop what you are doing! Make a backup of the disc (e.g. sector by sector image). Then try to recover either the backup or the original. In case there is a chance the original disc is failing make a second backup and try to fix the / recover from the first backup (in case the recovery process messes up the data on the first you can recreate it from the second backup). Note: you might remove the drive from the USB enclosure and connect it directly to depending on the software you use to create the image. Since the USB controller / USB case might cause the problem this might be a good idea anyway.

> Does anyone have suggestions for how to recover the disk and its data?

First of all you need to identify the problem. Is it a problem with the external case's controller, is it a deleted partition table etc.

There are loads of existing topics on how to recover drives and/or identify problems. Do a search and try those suggestions first. For example [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/81877/recover-hard-disk-data-after-deleting-partitions) for deleted partition tables. If you run into problems you can specify your question.

> Otherwise how does it know the partition type?

The partition type can be determined by scanning the drive for data that is NTFS specific.

> Does this imply that the disk is defective, quite apart from (perhaps) missing a partition table?

To check if the drive is failing/defective you will need to do a SMART check on the drive. Note: according to Tetsujin comment this is not possible on a Mac for an USB drive meaning you will have to remove the drive form the casing or use a different system (eg Windows).

Comment: Please consider leaving a suggestion on how to improve the answer when downvoting

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but how is the OP going to backup a disk that can't be mounted? Also, you can't check SMART status on a USB-attached drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for your comment, as far as I understood, the drive was mounted: `/dev/disk2`

Comment: No, OP says it won't mount & remains greyed out. `/dev` is not actually the mount point on Mac, it's `/Volumes` but `diskutil list` doesn't actually give any information as to whether a volume is currently mounted.

Comment: @Tetsujin he says the partition is greyed out "but the single partition is greyed out", if a device is not mounted the partition wouldn't show up at all. At least I never had a case where this was the case. I left a comment for the OP and asked to correct the confusion.

Comment: unmounted volumes are grey, mounted are black. e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ1H6.png

Comment: ok thnaks, sorry I'm not too familiar with the Mac GUI (well at least not from memory), I mainly use CLI (and Windows GUI).

Comment: @Tetsujin You can check SMART on USB drives - on Windows anyway.

Comment: @DavidPostill - that's the trouble with Windows-centric answers to Mac questions ;)) https://superuser.com/questions/1616395/smart-check-on-external-usb-hard-disk-on-macos

Comment: About the SMART check, I intentionally left out on how to check it. Also, in my view this is not a MAC specific question, although the OP will probable prefer a Mac solution I think his main goal is to recover the data (on whatever system is necessary)

Comment: @Tetsujin I hope we cleared the terminology now, so I would like to rephrase my comment: for a copy of the raw data the volume/partition does not need to mount. Backing up sectors doesn't have anything to do with partitions or filesystems, it's just the raw data on the drive. I think you are talking about a file backup?!

Comment: @Tetsujin I also added your info about smart readout on a mac, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: tbh, I've used Mac to fix Windows drives for so long it's become second nature. I do already have all the tools bought & paid for, which helps, also plenty of physical space & spare drives to play with, so I can install suspect drives internally on a spare Mac Pro & just let it go to work. I also have everything backed up with multiple redundancy, so if a drive dies, I'll just re-clone from the last backup & only need to data-scavenge perhaps the last day's work, at worst. I can have a dead boot drive from a Win machine back up & running within half an hour, usually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This morning I put the drive in the freezer for half an hour and then tried it. It worked and over the course of the day I have copied off the contents of the disk (only 20GB). The disk failed again just after the copy completed.

Comment: @WilliamMorris never tried that myself...  glad it worked. Consider writing an answer yourself, I'm sure this might help other users. How did you come up with the solution?